# How do truth values for entire implications work without given P and Q?

Tags: logic

I know that given an implication *P*→*Q*, we can assign a truth value to the entire propositional form given a P and Q using truth tables; however, is there a process for assigning a truth value to an implication when we don't consider a specific *P* and *Q*?For example, given the proposition "if x is even, it is divisible by 2", would the formal process for assigning a truth value to this proposition be that we obtain the truth value for the implication given every possible combination of *P* and *Q* which could be created for this scenario, and if the overall implication is ever false given these variables, we regard the entire thing as false and if not, we regard the entire thing as true?

Thanks

Comment: Please look up bound vs unbound variables.

Comment: Well no, naturally. A proposition whose truth depends on the instantiation of its variables is not a statement and thus does not have an intrinsic truth value, which is what you're asking for essentially. Yes, you can determine its truth values based on the possible combinations of truth values of its inputs, but none of them are more "correct" than the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are mixing up a few different notions. For instance, there is a subtle difference between

1. Checking if an argument is valid
2. Assigning a truth value to an implication

When we are checking in an argument is valid, then we must look at all cases. It is deemed invalid if there is a case when the premise is true but the conclusion is false.

When we are assigning a truth value to an implication, we need *not* look at all cases, but instead look up only the corresponding row in the truth table.

Therefore, it depends if we interpret "if x is even, it is divisible by 2" as an argument, which as the notation $P\vdash Q$, or as an implication, $P\to Q$.

This distinction may also be settled in [first order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic), with the introduction of [quantifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic)), whether we mean

$$\text{for all x where, if x is even, it is divisible by 2},$$
$$\text{i.e; }\forall x(P(x)\to Q(x))$$
or
$$\text{there exists an x where, if x is even, it is divisible by 2}.$$
$$\text{i.e; }\exists x(P(x)\to Q(x))$$

with a specified [domain of discourse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_discours).

Comment: thanks for the answer; to clarify, for assigning a truth value to an implication  P→Q, we would only do this when truth values for P and Q are already given to us; however if it is an argument P⊢Q, we ourselves consider every possible combination of P with Q which is possible given our scenario to decide it's truth value?

Comment: @God That is correct. However I will warn you that I have had some professors (usually ones not from the math department, but end up teaching a logic class) that conflate these notions (and sometimes the notations too), so if this is for a class, it would be best to ask the teacher what they mean.